# Why delete constructor in the Time Travel section of ReactJS tutorial

Tags: reactjs

In [this tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up-again), it says:

> Next, we’ll have the Board component receive squares and onClick props
>   from the Game component. Since we now have a single click handler in
>   Board for many Squares, we’ll need to pass the location of each Square
>   into the onClick handler to indicate which Square was clicked. Here
>   are the required steps to transform the Board component:
>
> Delete the constructor in Board.

Why delete the constructor when we are extending class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor in this case, is needed to set the initial state:

```
this.state = {
  history: [{
    squares: Array(9).fill(null),
  }],
  xIsNext: true,
};
```

Since state is being removed from the component entirely (It's now being passed down through props), it's better to omit the constructor entirely, as it will implicitly call the parent constructor, and initialize a blank state.

Comment: Is it a mistake to initialize with a constructor but doing only `super(props)`?

Comment: @CppLearner It's not a mistake, but it can lead to issues down the line. For instance, did you know that React.Component also has [`context` and `updater` arguments](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js#L21)? By omitting the constructor entirely, you ensure that the base class is initialized properly. Some users argue that if you use spread syntax, ie. (`class Example extends React.Component { constructor(...args) { super(...args); } }`) you're fine, because you're ensuring you're passing everything up to the extended class.

Comment: In all honesty though, you should skip constructors entirely now. Just use class properties, as babel/webpack all transpile these into their appropriate browser non-es6 counterparts, and clean up the codebase. For more info, check out: https://codeburst.io/use-class-properties-to-clean-up-your-classes-and-react-components-93185879f688